# Ideal climate/topography/etc. to settle on an Earth-like planet?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, climate, geography, space-colonization

If humans were to find a goldilocks planet with all of the conditions just right, what would be the best place to start a new colony? I figure access to abundant freshwater/aquifers, mild seasons, low relief to make agriculture easier, little to no seismic activity, and low incidences of dangerous weather (tornadoes, etc.) would make for a good spot.

Am I missing anything? Are there any places on Earth that would model this type of location or at least be very close to it?

Thanks.

*Edit*
The population is advanced enough to build a spaceship that can travel to another planet and settle it, whatever that is worth. There are natural predators to contend with, and that's an important item for the people to face. Essentially they are going to this planet with extensive knowledge of its geography and such and with the knowledge that there *is* life, but they don't really know any specifics on the life.

Comment: how technologically advance are these humans?

Comment: Might be worth looking up the [Hierarchy of Needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs) and starting from the bottom of the pyramid. One of the first things you have to differentiate between is "What do people _need_" vs "What do people _want_"?

Comment: Do your people have to contend with native species, or the planet is sterile?

Comment: Your description matches *many* places on Earth: Tidewater region of the Chesapeake Bay, Nile Delta, Fertile Crescent, many parts of Eastern China, etc. -- really, most river valleys, especially near the mouth.  Mild yearly flooding that you can set your calendar by is extremely helpful.

Comment: @dmm: Trouble is, most of the places you mention seem to be pretty nasty places to actually live - though granted that's often because humans have spent thousands of years screwing them up.  I'd suggest someplace like New Zealand's South Island, the northeastern US, or central France.

Comment: @jamesqf: LOL, I was thinking of them in their pristine condition.  Wouldn't recommend the DC area for new colonists.

Comment: @dmm: Nor would I :-)  But the DC area is what I'd call the Mid-Atlantic region.  Northeastern would be from about New York northwards.

Answer (score 2):

You should have some natural source of green power: Solar (i.e. not too overcast all the time), wind (like a steady offshore wind), geothermal, wave, fast river or waterfall. You also need to specify if there are predators to avoid: If so, flatland may not be the best place to be, mountains or hills can provide a natural high ground that is more defensible. Also, flat land can be much more prone to flooding, it isn't always the best place; and I should presume those coming from another planet can shape higher ground to their liking for the purpose of agriculture or ranching.